# SQL Server 2005 export specific data from the old database to the new database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, export

I have two databases DB_OLD and DB_NEW, both on SQL Server 2005, and I need to import data from DB_OLD to DB_NEW.
DB_NEW has the same tables from DB_OLD plus some new columns (but this won't be a problem since the columns accept NULL values).

There's a catch: I only have to import some data, not the entire DB_OLD.

In order to simply export the data from DB_OLD i tried to use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard in order to write my own select queries. The problem is that i don't know how to set multiple sources so i can import each select into the right table from DB_NEW.

I could create a view for each table and selecting there the data that needs to be transferred but I would like not to do this.

So, my question is: how can I use multiple sources without creating views? or is out there a tool that would better suit my needs?

Thanks experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it out just by using the `sp_addlinkedserver` and use custom select and insert queries